# Windows 7 DCOM not seeing interactive user

Tags: windows-7, dcom

I'm troubleshooting an issue having to do with Think N Do and Windows 7. I set the DCOM settings up as the manufacturer said they need to be. However, computers aren't connecting to each other. I have the computers set to automatically log on to an account at boot. This account is never logged out of.

What I'm finding is when I open a RDP to the computers they suddenly start to communicate with each other. As if it's finally seeing an interactive user. From my understanding of things by having an account automatically log on at boot that account is then the interactive user. Leaving RDP open at all times is not an option. Sometimes the customer forgets and closes out of the RDP session by Xing out of it, they don't log off so the program is still running in the background.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? It's an issue at a couple customer locations for me.